# Restart-Service on remote computer results in NoServiceFoundForGivenName, but Get-Service works

Tags: service, sql-server-2008-r2, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2, restart

I am trying to remotely restart the SQL Agent service on all my SQL Server instances. I run the following script from one of my development servers while logged into an account that has local administrator privileges on each of the servers listed in the CSV file. That file contains HostName and InstanceName for all my SQL instances, both on this development server and remote. All are either Windows Server 2008R2 or 2012, running either SQL Server 2008R2 or 2012. PowerShell is being Run As Administrator.

```
$Servers = Import-CSV C:\Temp\InstanceList.csv
ForEach ($Line In $Servers)
{
  $sqlHostName = $Line.hostName
  $sqlInstanceName = if ($Line.instanceName -eq "") {$Line.instanceName} else {("$" + $Line.instanceName)}
  $serviceName = if ($sqlInstanceName -eq "") {"SQLSERVERAGENT"} else {"SQLAgent" + $sqlInstanceName}
  Get-Service -computer $sqlHostName ($serviceName)
  Get-Service -computer $sqlHostName ($serviceName) | Restart-Service
}
```

It succeeds on the local machine's instances but fails on the remote instances. Here is the error I see for remote default instances. The first line shows that I have the correct service name, and the next line claims it doesn't exist:

```
Running  SQLSERVERAGENT     SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)
Restart-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'SQLSERVERAGENT'.
At line:11 char:70
+   Get-Service -computer $sqlHostName ($serviceName) | Restart-Service <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SQLSERVERAGENT:String) [Restart-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RestartServiceCommand
```

Enable-Remoting had been previously been run locally on each server.

Why is Get-Service able to display the service name, but then Restart-Service claims that the service doesn't exist. It feels like it must be a permissions issue, but I don't know how to resolve it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because Get-Service is still running locally; it doesn't know about the -Computer parameter from your previous command in the pipeline, and it doesn't support -Computer like Get-Service does. To use Restart-Service for a remote service, you have a couple of options:

**Option 1: Use Enter-PSSession**

You can enter a remote PowerShell session on the computer in question by using Enter-PSSession. When you do, it essentially opens a shell on the remote computer and any command you give it, will run. Enter-PSSession also supports the -Credential parameter, so if the account you're running locally isn't an administrative account with permissions on the remote computer, you can create a Credential Object first and then use that. The code might look something like this:

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $Credential
```

When you run that, your prompt will change: it will ad the name of the remote computer in square brackets (to let you know you're executing commands against a different host). It probably also is going to default to the users\documents folder on the remote host, like so:

```
[ComputerName]: PS C:\Users\Username\Documents>
```

Now, any command you run will run at the target computer. You won't need the -Computer on Get-Service anymore. So you can just run:

```
Get-Service ($serviceName) | Restart-Service
```

*Just make sure when you're done, you use Exit-PSSession to return to your local prompt.*

**Option 2: Use Invoke-Command**

Another option (and one that might lend itself better to the automation you're doing) is to use Invoke-Command. Invoke-Command supports both -Credential and -ComputerName parameters, as well as a -ScriptBlock parameter. ScriptBlock is neat because it allows you to easily pass and modify code that has parameters of thier own. So in your example above, you could do something like this:

```
$ScriptBlock = {Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "SQL*"} | Restart-Service}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
```

Based on how what you're trying to do, I'd rewrite your script like so:

```
$Servers = Import-CSV C:\Temp\InstanceList.csv
$ScriptBlock = {param([string] $RemoteServiceName)  Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $RemoteServiceName} | Restart-Service}

ForEach ($Line In $Servers)
{
  $sqlHostName = $Line.hostName
  $sqlInstanceName = if ($Line.instanceName -eq "") {$Line.instanceName} else {("$" + $Line.instanceName)}
  $serviceName = if ($sqlInstanceName -eq "") {"SQLSERVERAGENT"} else {"SQLAgent" + $sqlInstanceName}
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $sqlHostName -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $serviceName
}
```

I'm using your loop logic, but I am using the variables you get from your .CSV file to specify the -ComputerName where I want Invoke-Command to run, and I am using a ScriptBlock with an ArgumentList and Parameters to provide the values that ultimately get run.

If you want to learn more about a couple of the concepts, here's some linkage:

1. ScriptBlock info: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847893.aspx
2. Invoke-Command: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx

**Option 3: Use Methods On An Object**

Of course, it doesn't need to be that hard. You can use Get-Service to get a service to a variable, and then use the .Restart() method on the object. While you can't pass the object to Restart-Service, you *can* just invoke the method and it'll restart that service, even remotely:

```
$Servers = Import-CSV C:\Temp\InstanceList.csv
ForEach ($Line In $Servers)
{
    $sqlHostName = $Line.hostName
    $sqlInstanceName = if ($Line.instanceName -eq "") {$Line.instanceName} else {("$" + $Line.instanceName)}
    $serviceName = if ($sqlInstanceName -eq "") {"SQLSERVERAGENT"} else {"SQLAgent" + $sqlInstanceName}
    $Service = Get-Service -computer $sqlHostName ($serviceName)
    $Service.Restart()
}
```

And that's one thing that's great about PowerShell. None of those answers are "wrong" in that you can use any of them; they're all potential solutions, and I'm sure there are even more out there.